# In a Discord.Net bot, how would I wait for a certain amount of time to pass while remaining responsive?

Tags: c#, discord.net

So, I'm making a Discord.Net bot in C# and I want to know how to wait for a certain amount of time while remaining responsive. Here's some pseudo-code to show what I mean.

```
Wait for 30 seconds while checking for input
If I have found input within this 30 seconds, echo it in the current channel.
If not, call the DoStuff() method.
```

How would I achieve this in C#? This thing above is just an example, not the real thing (obviously).

Comment: There tens, if not hundreds of ways to implement that with your description. If you already have code in place to do (part) of this, you should include in the question.

Comment: I don't have code to implement part of it. I just came here for suggestions on how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless Discord.Net has some built in functionality that supports your problem, you'll be able achieve this using multi threading.

I recommend taking a look at [this website](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_multithreading.htm) if you choose to take the multi threading approach.

Comment: Could I have a simple code example in normal C# code? I don't understand how to use multithreading. Sorry.

Comment: Ignore me. I know exactly what to do now. I bought the book named "C# 3.0 in a Nutshell" and it explained multithreading better.